# Rendering riot routes while render

Tags: koa, isomorphic-javascript, riot.js

I am trying to render my riot tags on the server side and this works fine. The tags gets rendered on the server side and gets loaded on the client. Problem arises when I try to define my tags along with the definition of my routes using riot.route. The tags gets compiled to its corresponding Js files but on hitting my route it hits an internal server error and the error logged in the console is riot.route is not a function.

Code for my riot route in the script section of my tag.

```
<script>
        var self = this;
        this.data = opts.datastore
        this.page = opts.datastore[0]


        riot.route(function(id)
        {   
            this.page = this.data.filter(function(r) { return r.id == id })[0] || {}
            this.update();

        })



this.doUpdate = function update()
    {
        opts.remarks = this.fname.value;
    }


    </script>
```

The data here comes from my server.js file via the datastore option and is a json data.